# ValueError: could not convert string to float, (numpy.string_)

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am trying to convert an array of `np.string_`s that are all representing numbers into floats for mathematical use. I am reading data from a fits file using pyfits.

```
data = read_fits(datafile)
glon = np.asarray(data['GLON'], dtype = float); glat = data['GLAT']
# heliocentric distance in kpc
D = data['D'] 
for i in range(len(glon)):
    #glon[i] = (glon[i]).astype(float)
```

I have left a couple of my attempts to change the type, but float() and all similar operations I have heard of are failing. Yet I do not think I have a bogus value as I have looked through a `print` of the data after reading and it is all numerical.

Comment: What is the value inside data['GLON']? What errors are you getting when you say "failing"?

Comment: The value of data['GLON'] is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Comment: The error is `ValueError: could not convert string to float` if I attempt to convert in any way. It is `unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'numpy.string_' and 'int'` for my other purposes.

Comment: What's the dtype of `data['GLON']`.  I'm guessing `np.string_`.  Also you could experiment with `[float(i) for i in data['GLON`]]` (assuming it is 1d).

Answer (score 1):

Row [0] had blank characters...

Comment: I thought it was ok to answer your own question.  In fact as a reader I prefer it that way.  I tend to focus on questions without an answer, and often skip ones with an accepted one.